# ER Diagram - relationhip

Tags: sql, database

What can be the best relationship for disease and symptom? 
I think should be Many to Many (n2n).

But if I want to retrive desease once user selected diseases
how will be the query for it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about what you are looking for?

From what I understand from your question,
A diesase can have many symptoms.
Different symptoms can point to different diseases. It is a many to many relationship.

Are you constructing an ER diagram for a schema ? Or are you trying to write a query to retrieve data ?